# Sorting A Custom List C#

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a list of windows but it is not in the order I want them. I'm able to get the windows into string from the title - they are being put into a list of windows. I want to sort this list in a specific order with Estimate 1st, Control Center 2nd, and Login 3rd. This is the order I desire. I have know idea on how to go about it but I want to sort it before it goes into the foreach loop.

```
    private void CloseMainWindows(IEnumerable<Window> Windows)
    {
        var winList = Windows.ToList();

        winList.Sort()//This is where I want to sort the list. 

        foreach (Window window in winList)
        {
            if (window.Title.Contains("Estimate"))
            {
                Estimate.closeEstimateWindow();
            }
            if (window.Title.Contains("Control Center"))
            {
                ContorlCenter.CloseContorlCenter();
            }
            if (window.Title.Contains("Login"))
            {
                login.ClickCanel();
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: `Windows.OrderBy(...)`?

Comment: The order of that foreach matters?

Comment: By the way you misspelled `ContorlCenter`.

Comment: Do you have any other information on your window class besides the name. Since the names are not in alphabetical order, an order by will not work.

Comment: @StuartSmith: `OrderBy` won't work directly on the name. But he knows the specific items, so he can transform the name to a scalar value.

Comment: Good point I like your Answer Jim

Comment: @zenadix Thanks I was in a hurry sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to have a lookup function:

```
int GetTitleIndex(string s)
{
    if (s.Contains("Estimate")) return 0;
    if (s.Contains("Control Center")) return 1;
    if (s.Contains("Login")) return 2;
}
```

Then, to sort, you lookup the indexes:

```
winList.Sort((x, y) => GetTitleIndex(x).CompareTo(GetTitleIndex(y)));
```

Alternatively, you could create the list directly using LINQ's `OrderBy`:

```
var winList = Windows.OrderBy(GetTitleIndex).ToList();
```

And in fact in your case you don't even need the intermediate list:

```
foreach (var window in Windows.OrderBy(GetTitleIndex))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: That you this is what I was looking for!

Comment: I would also appreciate if you up the question. I have no points what so ever.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
List<Type> data = new List<Type>();
data.Sort(new Comparison<Type>(Compare));
private static int Compare(Type x, Type y)
{
   //you can compare them like so : 
   //I'll show you an example just for the sake of illustrating how : 
   if(x.Name.ToString().Length > y.Name.ToString().Length) return 1;
   else return -1;
   //the logic for the comparison is up to you.
   //compare the 2 elements.
}
```

Comment: Funny,because it doesn't compile because I did compare the two strings in a wrong way. The rest of the stuff is fine

Comment: Okay ... I retract my comment.